# Curl -xget gives an error in powershell 5.1

Tags: windows, powershell, curl

As you can see, `curl -xget` is working fine in PS 7.2 and cmd, but gives an error in PS 5.1.

> Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'xget'.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot of the error, Powershell windows side by side]

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. See [ask].

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you are calling `curl` in cmd and PowerShell Core it is calling the executable in `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\curl.exe` while in PowerShell Desktop it is calling the `Invoke-WebRequest` command which does not have the `xget` parameter

If you want to use `xget` in PowerShell you have to use the `curl.exe` command instead

Answer (score -1):

```
-X ≈ --request 
-x ≈ --proxy
```

Maybe you should've used the capital letters in `-XGET`.